# Stylometry with R-Studio: Error with command oppose from package "stylo" - why is my corpus not usable?

Tags: r, nlp, format, txt, corpus

I run a stylometric analysis of poetry in R Studio using the package "stylo". I want to compare two sets of texts via function oppose. I created subdirectories in my working directory for the partitions "male" and "female.

```
# create folders for the genders
dir.create("female")
dir.create("male")

# copy the poems to the corresponding folders
file.copy(poems_female, "female")
file.copy(poems_male, "male")

# oppose
oppose(gui = TRUE,
       primary.corpus = "female",
       secondary.corpus = "male")
```

Then this error occurs:

The object you've specified as your corpus cannot be used.
It should be a list containing particular text samples
(vectors containing sequencies of words/n-grams or other features).
The samples (elements of the list) should have their names.
Alternatively, try to build your corpus from text files (default).

really didn't know what to do, because the samples are .txt files with plain text, which should be working just fine

Comment: I don't know the package but apparently it expects the input to be provided after tokenization. could it be that you forgot to tokenize the text maybe?

Comment: no, function oppose is tokenizing it before calculating, no need to do it before

Comment: Ok, but the message says that there is an issue with the input format of the function so there's a good chance that the tokenization doesn't return the expected format. Can show what the data looks like after tokenization?